# Using Linux tools to allow a user in a domain to access only certain computers

Tags: linux, active-directory, samba, domain-controller

I ran samba-ad-dc domain controller on Debian Bullseye. No problem to create users and groups, organizational units, etc and to join windows or Linux computers to domain. But there is other task: On Windows Server using "Active Directory users and computers", in users profile account tab under button "Log on to..." - you can specify the computers the users is allowed to logon to. This option works for every computer - Windows or Linux with configured samba client.

So I concluded that these are not group policies (otherwise these login restrictions would not work for Linux computers). The problem is that I cannot find any information how to solve such task using Linux tools, such as "samba-tool", "net" or maybe changing/adding LDAP attributes to user or computer entities. Is it generally possible?

Comment: The clients look for an attribute `userworkstations` on the user account in LDAP. If your Samba directory does not have that attribute, it can be added. See this page for examples: https://www.sigma-uk.net/tech/ubuntu_ldap#samba_v3

Comment: @GregAskew yes, it works: adding and modifying attribute `userworkstations`. Thanks!